# Cisco 3750 802.1x -- Invalid Eapol packet length

Tags: mtu, radius, ieee-802.1x

Having a tough time here getting **EAP-TLS** to work. I am converting from a EAP-PEAP solution to **EAP-TLS** and have done the steps required for PKI so as to be not a certificate issue. (server and client certs signed by same CA)

I believe there is an issue with MTU sizes based on the logs below and the following Cisco Forums I've found. Listed below are the posts. However after performing the **Framed-MTU = 1344** and changing it to different sizes, I see no difference on the Cisco 3750s logs. Always errors with I**nvalid Eapol Packet length = 1492.**

Has anyone run into this before? I am using Win2008R2 NPS

**Framed-MTU** workaround = https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771164%28WS.10%29.aspx and https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11087011/eap-tls-authentication-failure

Why I'm thinking this is a Fragmentation issue = http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/8021x/118634-technote-eap-00.html#anc18

Basically my set-up = http://networklessons.com/wireless/peap-and-eap-tls-on-server-2008-and-cisco-wlc/

```
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/7): Received an EAPOL frame
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): Received pkt saddr =f0de.f17b.4d9f , daddr = 0180.c200.0003, pae-ether-type = 888e.0100.0006
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/7): Received an EAP packet
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: EAPOL pak dump rx
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: EAPOL Version: 0x1  type: 0x0  length: 0x0006
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/7): Received an EAP packet from f0de.f17b.4d9f
Mar 10 17:33:08.889: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): dot1x_sendRespToServer: Response sent to the server from 0x9C000260 (f0de.f17b.4d9f)
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): Sending EAPOL packet to f0de.f17b.4d9f
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): Role determination not required
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): Sending out EAPOL packet
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: EAPOL pak dump Tx
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: EAPOL Version: 0x3  type: 0x0  length: 0x029B
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: EAP code: 0x1  id: 0x5  length: 0x029B type: 0xD
Mar 10 17:33:08.897: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/7): EAPOL packet sent to client 0x9C000260 (f0de.f17b.4d9f)
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): Role determination not required
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/7): Queuing an EAPOL pkt on Authenticator Q
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-ev:Enqueued the eapol packet to the global authenticator queue
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: EAPOL pak dump rx
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: EAPOL Version: 0x1  type: 0x0  length: 0x05D4
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-ev:
dot1x_auth_queue_event: Int Gi1/0/7 CODE= 2,TYPE= 13,LEN= 1492

Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/7): Received an EAPOL frame
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/7): Received pkt saddr =f0de.f17b.4d9f , daddr = 0180.c200.0003, pae-ether-type = 888e.0100.05d4
Mar 10 17:33:08.923: dot1x-err(Gi1/0/7): Invalid Eapol packet length = 1492
```

Comment: Note this in the document you linked:  For RADIUS, there is a Framed-MTU attribute defined in RFC 2865:

"This Attribute indicates the Maximum Transmission Unit to be configured for the user, when it is not negotiated by some other means (such as PPP). It MAY be used in Access-Accept packets. It MAY be used in an Access-Request packet as a hint by the NAS to the server that it would prefer that value, **but the server is not required to honor the hint** "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you test this out, after hours, requires a switch reboot?

**Switch Config:**

```
conf t
!
system mtu jumbo 9000
```

**Windows Server 2008R2 config:**

```
adjust MTU to 9000
```

This may help. Take a look at this article if you haven't already figured this out: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/8021x/118634-technote-eap-00.html